# Can't download GAE source code

Tags: google-app-engine

Here's the command I'm using:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A --application= appid
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py:42: DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead
  os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'lib', 'django_0_96'),
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_login.py:33: DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead
  import md5
Host: appengine.google.com
Fetching file list...
Email: [email]  
Password for [email]: 
Error 400: --- begin server output ---

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.
--- end server output ---
```

My email/pw is correct. Can anyone help me translate this error?

Comment: Should there be a space between `--application=` and `appid`?

Comment: I receive another error when there isn't: appcfg.py: error: "download_app" expects one non-option argument, found 0.

Comment: You can't download an app that was uploaded before the download_app feature was added (1.4.1?).  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the documentation, the format for that command is:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <application-id> -V <application-version> <output-dir>
```

Looks like there's a bug in the documentation, as when I try it, the `<output-dir>` parameter is *required*.

So your call ought to look like this to download to the current directory (`.`)

```
appcfg.py download_app -A appid .
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself.  The order of arguments makes a difference.  The appid and version (optional) need to appear before "download_app".

The following worked for me:

```
appcfg.py -A appid download_app ../../path/to/directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

The command below worked for me:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A s~xxx -V 1.374941992621083247 .
```

My site is `http://xxx.appspot.com` but instead of `-A xxx`, I used `-A s~xxx`.

`s~xxx` and `version_id 1.374941992621083247` can be taken from the url in your App Engine console like this:

```
https://appengine.google.com/logs?&app_id=s~xxx&version_id=1.374941992621083247
```